# integrating user control to a form in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

I have a visual studio project, in which I have a form and a user control. I have dragged the user control on the form but it does not bult. I receive the error "'name of the User cntrol' is not a member of 'the name of the form'"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows.

I removed the namespace of the project in the h file of the user control.
Then I include NameOfTheUserControl.h in the h file of the form.